# How do I export a Sass variable to Javascript?

Tags: sass, storybook, rollupjs

I have an Sass setup in my application that provides some [custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) as well as Sass `$variables`.

```
:root { --my-variable: #FFFFFF; }

$my-variable: var(--my-variable) !default;
```

And I would love to export those variables to Js using the `:export` tag, so that I can present them in the storybook.

**For example:**

```
:export {
  myVar: var(--my-variable)
  ...
}
```

But the only thing I was able to achieve, is that in Js I get the string literal, not the variable associated value, in this case `#FFFFFF`.

Do I need to do anything specific in my configuration to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the fact that only browsers can interpret custom properties. If custom property is declared like this:

```
:root { --body-backgroundColor: #fafafa; }

body { background-color: var(--body-backgroundColor); }
```

You can manipulate `--body-backgroundColor:` via Js, however Sass will interpret your `$my-variable: var(--my-variable) !default;` as a string, since it can't associate a custom property with its value.

The best practice here is  to pass the *variable* inside the custom property.

```
$myVar: #fff !default;

:root { --my-var: #{$myVar}; }

body { background-color: var(--my-var); }

:export {
  myVar: $myVar;
  ...
}
```